# How to scale up docker instances using Apache Marathon REST API.?

Tags: rest, docker, mesos, marathon

Is it possible to scale up and down number of docker containers/instances using **Mesosphere Marathon REST API?**

Endpoint **`GET /deployments`** seems to be only option to see the next possible operation.
How to scale up the instances using REST API (programmatically: possibly using curl script and without using the Marathon Web interface)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use PUT with JSON with only field `"instances"` with desired instances count (e.g., 2) and application ID (e.g., `/foo`).

```
PUT <marathon-url>/v2/apps/foo

{ "id": "/foo", "instances": 2 }
```

**Note:** [Marathon 1.4 deprecates PUT semantic.](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon/releases/tag/v1.4.0)

> A PUT on /v2/apps has a PATCH like semantic: All values that are not defined in the json, will not update existing values.
>   This was always the default behaviour in Marathon versions.
>   For backward compatibility, we will not change this behaviour, but let users opt in for a proper PUT.
>   The next version of Marathon will use PATCH and PUT as two separate actions.

Comment: Thanks @janisz. One thing I observed that url becomes something like :          <marathon-url>/v2/apps//foo. So with "/" in front of appid.

Comment: Hi @janisz, one more question. How to know number of running instances of specific appid (say /foo).?

Comment: AppID is prefixed with  `/` to ensure it's absolute group ID. To get current instances you need to call `GET <marathon-url>/v2/apps/foo`. If you want to get running/staged/killing instances try `GET <marathon-url>/v2/apps/foo?embed=app.counts` and look for tasksStaged, tasksRunning, tasksHealthy, tasksUnhealthy